# Can't add element by the button value in angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, button, click

I want to add the button's value to my program.

First I show some buttons.

```
<button *ngFor="let row of buttonTable.rows" mat-raised-button class="btn btn-sm" value={{row}} (click)="addLab(this.value)">{{row}}</button>
```

My addLab() method is

```
  addLab(value:any):void{
  this.formTable.rows.push([value]);
  }
```

And my buttonTable is like this.

```
declare interface oneLineTable {
  rows: string[][];
}
```

But I can't get the value by this click method. Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try to pass 'row' instead of 'this.value' in addLab click event:

```
<button *ngFor="let row of buttonTable.rows" mat-raised-button class="btn btn- sm" (click)="addLab(row)">{{row}}</button>
```

Comment: Great !  :) Please just upvote my answer and verify as best answer if that is ok with you! Thank you, it means a lot !

Answer (score 0):

try this [value]="row" and pass $event in your click methond

```
<button *ngFor="let row of buttonTable.rows" mat-raised-button class="btn btn-sm" [value]="row" (click)="addLab($event)">{{row}}</button>
```

and get the value like this

```
addLab(event) {
 console.log(event.target.value);
 }
```